# MySQL Insert if Condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I Have this cat id - post id relation table.

```
+----+--------+---------+
| id | cat_id | post_id |
|    |        |         |
| 1  |   11   |   32    |
| 2  |   ...  |   ...   |
+----+--------+---------+
```

I use `SELECT WHERE cat_id = 11 AND post_id = 32` and then if no result found, I do `INSERT`.
Can I rewrite these two queries in One?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
insert into cats_rel(cat_id, post_id)
    select 11, 32
    where not exists (select 1 from cats_rel where cat_id = 11 and post_id = 32);
```

EDIT:

Oops.  That above doesn't work in MySQL because it is missing a `from` clause (works in many other databases, though).  In any case, I usually write this putting the values in a subquery, so they only appear in the query once:

```
insert into cats_rel(cat_id, post_id)
    select toinsert.cat_id, toinsert.post_id
    from (select 11 as cat_id, 32 as post_id) toinsert
    where not exists (select 1
                      from cats_rel cr
                      where cr.cat_id = toinsert.cat_id and cr.post_id = toinsert.post_id
                     );
```

Comment: sorry, whats `rt`? my table name is cats_rel and your query didn't work

Comment: `rt` is a table alias.  It actually isn't needed for this query.

Comment: I get this error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where not exists (select 1 from cats_rel where cat_id = 11 and message_id = 32)' at line 3

Comment: I don't know what is toinsert and cr and what does this mean "they only appear in the query once" but... Well Done Gordon Linoff, this Did the job!

Comment: `toinsert` and `cr` are table aliases.  The values only appear once in this query -- in the subquery.  Everywhere else, they are referred to by column names.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Replace

```
REPLACE INTO 'yourtable'
SET `cat_id` = 11, `post_id` = 32;
```

if the record exists it will overwrite it otherwise it will be created;

Update :
For this to work you should add a unique key to the pair of columns not only one

```
ALTER TABLE yourtable ADD UNIQUE INDEX cat_post_unique (cat_id, post_id);
```

Comment: your query just inserts and inserts. I run this 5 times and now have 5 11 and 32!

Comment: ALTER TABLE yourtable ADD UNIQUE(cat_id ,post_id );

Comment: added unique and any any execution ruins the previous record. I need to have many posts linked to one category. in this way just one post can be linked to a category!

Comment: you should add unique to the pair of columns  not only one

ALTER TABLE `yourtable`
ADD UNIQUE INDEX `cat_post_unique` (`cat_id`, `post_id`);

Comment: hi, please edit your answer and note the last comment in the answer, so I can mark it as accepted, as it is simpler than the currently accepted answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

We can use "from dual" clause for MySQL:

```
insert into cats_rel(cat_id, post_id)
select 11, 32 from dual
where not exists (select 1 from cats_rel where cat_id = 11 and post_id = 32);
```