# MySQL case execute a query on the basis of result returned from a query

Tags: mysql

What I want to achieve is,
If the number of rows returned by the query:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM `games` WHERE cateID=2 AND active=1
```

is EQUAL to 0, I want to run an inserting query:

```
INSERT INTO games(cateID ,time,users,active)
                VALUES ('2', '1', '0', '1')
```

I tried using case like this:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN SELECT count(*) FROM `games` WHERE cateID=2 AND active=1)=0
    THEN INSERT INTO games(cateID ,time,users,active)
                VALUES ('2', '1', '0', '1')
END
```

But it returns error as:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT count(*) FROM `games` WHERE cateID=2 AND active=1)=0
    THEN INSERT INTO' at line 1
```

Note: Both queries when executed separately, execute without any error.
How do I achieve this ?

**EDIT:**

Also tried this with IF,

```
SELECT if(count(*)==0,INSERT INTO games(cateID ,time,users,active)
                VALUES ('2', '1', '0', '1')) FROM `games` WHERE cateID=2 AND active=1
```

Still gives the same error.
**EDIT 2:**
By the suggested comment,

```
INSERT INTO games(cateID ,time,users,active)
select '2','2','0','1'
where (SELECT count(*) FROM `games` WHERE cateID=2 AND active=1) <= 0
```

Still gives error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL INSERT IF (custom if statements)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6854996/mysql-insert-if-custom-if-statements)

Comment: did try that. Look at the edit 2.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18421905/mysql-insert-if-condition

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DECLARE
  games_count INTEGER;
BEGIN
  SELECT count(*) FROM `games` WHERE cateID=2 AND active=1 ;
  IF games_count = 0 THEN
    INSERT INTO games(cateID ,time,users,active) VALUES ('2', '1', '0', '1');
  END IF;
END;
```

Comment: You need to select INTO games_count SELECT count(*) FROM games WHERE cateID=2 AND active=1 INTO games_count... P.S. You beat me for few second i just prepare to press Post Your Answer :D

Comment: Gives an error:  #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE
  games_count INTEGER' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

before to do the insert, check the select query. if the select query return 0 records  nothing is inserting with the insert query.

```
select  cateID,'2' as time,'0' as users,active 
FROM 
   (select count(*) as countRecord,cateID,active 
    from games 
    where  CATEID=2 and active=1 group by cateID,active) G   
where countRecord <= 0  
group by cateID, active,time,users
```

Comment: Still error #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'active=1 group by cateID,active)
where countRecord <= 0  
group by cateID, activ' at line 5

Comment: @kritya Oups sorry I just forget the `and` in where clause `CATEID=2 active=1` i' I have corrected this